# Sed: can't define the pattern correctly, can you please assist?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to add "ARG1$" to the end of this line:

```
command[check_net_speed]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_net_speed.sh $
```

I've tried:

```
sed -e 's/^command\[check_net_speed\]$/$ARG1$/g' /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
sed -e 's/.*speed.*/$ARG1$/g' /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
```

But none did the trick... what's the right way to catch the pattern of the "check_net_speed" command and add "ARG1$" at the end of the line, so the line will look like this:

```
command[check_net_speed]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_net_speed.sh $ARG1$
```

Comment: would be good to have provided some more context, because many answers popped and you ended up accepting one without giving the reason. I am not complaining for it, of course, but some clarifications on the exact desired output would be good. Otherwise the question doesn't have much value for other people reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
sed -e 's/^command\[check_net_speed\].*/&ARG1$/g' input
command[check_net_speed]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_net_speed.sh $ARG1$
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry, I didnt get you. Are you pointing out some mistakes? :/

Comment: I don't see how this is checking for the existence of `$` at the end of the line.

Comment: @fedorqui It doesnt checks so because its not required. From what OP wrote *catch the pattern of the "check_net_speed" command and add "ARG1$" at the end of the line*, he just needs to append `$ARG1$` when the pattarn `check_net_speed` is caught

Comment: well it is a bit unclear because in the beginning it is indicating so by saying `to the end of this line...` containing this line `...$`

Comment: @fedorqui. This will work if that line have to end with $ `sed -e 's/^command\[check_net_speed\].*\$$/&ARG1$/g;q'`. Note `;q` part in this command which means quit after first match.

Comment: @jujj yes, indeed. Escaping the `$` is what I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27400895/1983854). Note you can use an initial `/ /` to just perform this on the lines matching a specific pattern; this way, you won't try to do it on every line.

Comment: @fedorqui. Your code will replace every line with that pattern in the file, check comment of OP on the first answer. OP only want `one specific line` to be replaced, so `;q` is necessary.

Comment: @jujj well [OPs comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400809/sed-cant-define-the-pattern-correctly-can-you-please-assist/27400938?noredirect=1#comment43246690_27400838) can be interpreted in different ways. Let's just see what his feedback is.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R understood me correctly, I wanted to catch only the line which contained the "check_net_speed" and add ARG1$ at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sed command like below,

```
sed -e '/^command\[check_net_speed\]/s~$~ARG1$~' file
```

`/^command\[check_net_speed\]/` matches the lines which starts with `command[check_net_speed]` and it do the replacement on those matched lines.

`$` in the regex part means end of the line. So the above command replaces the end of the line anchor with `ARG1$`

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'command[check_net_speed]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_net_speed.sh $' | sed -e '/^command\[check_net_speed\]/s~$~ARG1$~'
command[check_net_speed]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_net_speed.sh $ARG1$
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` has a special meaning: end of line. To treat it as a literal, you have to escape it:

```
sed '/^command\[check_net_speed\].*\$/s/$/ARG1$/' file
```

This will replace the end of line (indicated by `$` alone) with the string `ARG1$`. So at the end, `ARG1$` will be appended to the line.

The `/command/` part is used to perform this replacement only in the lines containing the string `command`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
command[check_net_speed]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_net_speed.sh $
ddd
$  sed '/^command\[check_net_speed\].*\$/s/$/ARG1$/' a
command[check_net_speed]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_net_speed.sh $ARG1$
ddd
```

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to [nu11p01n73R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150943/nu11p01n73r)'s answer. Use

```
sed -e 's/^command\[check_net_speed\].*\$$/&ARG1$/g;q' /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
```

`;q` after substitution command means stop processing the rest of this file after first match.